# Boot ubuntu 16.04 from grub

Tags: grub2

How to Fix an Ubuntu System When it won't boot from grub with error:

> you need to load the kernel first .

And when I try to load the kernel with:

```
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
```

An error appears with:

> file vmlinuz not found

When I use `ls boot`, I can only see `initrd.img`, but not `vmlinuz`.
Does anyone have any suggestion, please?

Comment: And why are we loading the kernel by ourselves? In any case use the `ls` to find where the vmlinuz file is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Insert ubuntu 16.04 image  and start live CD**

**2. locate the boot partition dev/sdaX**

```
  # df -h   -->dev/sda1
```

**3. Mount file systems:**

```
  # mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt 

  # mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

  # mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc

  # mount --bind /run /mnt/run

  # mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/sys
```

**4. chroot the system:**

```
  # chroot /mnt
```

**5. repair Linux kernel:**

```
 # apt-get update

 # apt-get install linux-firmware linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

**6. reboot**

Answer (score 0):

### Booting Ubuntu 16.04

For 64 bit versions of Ubuntu 16.04 and prior use "vmlinuz.efi" not "vmlinuz".

Comment: Vmlinuz.efi not found

Comment: @Mohammed tidjane: please have a look inside your Ubuntu ISO or USB. There should be a folder named casper. Do you see vmlinuz.efi file in there?